# crystal reports how to display full page with header and footer per record in detail section

Tags: crystal-reports

I have setup a Crystal report which displays a header, detail (3 records) and footer sections. In the detail section, I only want one record to show per page but with the header and footer intact. So in other words, I want each page to show the header, detail (1 record) and the footer.

In the Details area of Section Expert, I have set the New Page After 1 record setting in the Paging tab. Following which the report now shows the header and 1 record in the first page, the second record in the second page (without a header or footer) and the third record in the last page with a footer. See picture below: [section expert setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmlFI.png)

My expected output is

## Page 1

Header
Record 1
Footer

## Page 2

Header
Record 2
Footer

## Page 3

Header
Record 3
Footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Page Header/Footer for content you wish to see repeated on every page.
Or you can set grouping to result in a separate group per each detail section, and then use GH/GF sections.

In the section expert for the detail section, Paging tab, you can set the property of 'New Page Before' to place each detail record on a new page.